# Sending a message to an embedded HornetQ from an external application

Tags: spring-boot, hornetq

I am using spring-boot 1.2.2.

I have an embedded hornet queue setup in `application.properties`:

```
spring.hornetq.mode=embedded
spring.hornetq.embedded.enabled=true
spring.hornetq.embedded.queues=myQueue
```

I want to add a message to "myQueue" from an external application (not the one with the embedded queue).  Is this possible?

In the other application (the one without the embedded hornetq), I tried creating a connectionFactory that points to the embedded hornetq server but I don't really know what port I should be using.  According to the spring-boot [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-messaging) it says it is only valid for "native" mode.

```
spring.hornetq.mode= # connection mode (native, embedded)
spring.hornetq.host=localhost # hornetQ host (native mode)
spring.hornetq.port=5445 # hornetQ port (native mode)
```

here is my code so far:

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class HornetQConfig {

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory =
                new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(10);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheProducers(false);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(hornetQConnectionFactory());
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HornetQConnectionFactory hornetQConnectionFactory() {

        HornetQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new HornetQConnectionFactory(false, transportConfiguration());
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("host", "localhost");
        map.put("port", 5445);
        TransportConfiguration configuration =
                new TransportConfiguration(
                        "org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory", map);
        return configuration;
    }

}
```

And then:

```
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L)
public void send() {
    this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("myQueue", "Hello from external app");
}
```

But I am getting a connection problem.

```
Failed to create session factory; nested exception is HornetQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s)
```

Comment: I'm looking at something similar (eventually I want to cluster two embedded HornetQ setups), but haven't figured it out yet either. I think for a start, you would need to add a transport on the embedded server that allows connecting on an actual port, by default only an InVMConnectorFactory will be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the embedded HornetQ server is configured with only an `InVMAcceptorFactory` by default. You need to add an AcceptorFactory that actually listens on a port, like `NettyAcceptorFactory`.

You can use the `HornetQConfigurationCustomizer` to configure this. Below example uses a hardcoded host/port, but you can easily create your own properties to make this configurable.

```
@Bean
public HornetQConfigurationCustomizer hornetCustomizer() {
    return new HornetQConfigurationCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Configuration configuration) {
            Set<TransportConfiguration> acceptors = configuration.getAcceptorConfigurations();
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("host", "localhost");
            params.put("port", "5445");
            TransportConfiguration tc = new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), params);
            acceptors.add(tc);
        }
    };
}
```

In your application with the embedded server, you configure it as embedded (as I believe you already have anyway, just to make sure):

```
spring.hornetq.mode=embedded
spring.hornetq.embedded.enabled=true
spring.hornetq.embedded.queues=myQueue
```

And in your "other" application that you want to connect to the embedded server, you configure HornetQ in native mode:

```
spring.hornetq.mode=native
spring.hornetq.host=localhost
spring.hornetq.port=5445
```

Comment: I could not get this working.  Both applications start up fine with no errors. When I attempt to send a message  I cam getting `org.hornetq.api.core.HornetQNotConnectedException: HQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.`

Comment: I started using a different port "5455" and everything started working ... not sure why.